# sparc assembly - add and addcc

Tags: assembly, sparc, risc

I have just read some old courses on SPARC Assembly and I don't remember the difference between "add" and "addcc" instructions (like also sub and subcc).

Could you explain to me this difference ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cc` suffix indicates that the instruction sets the condition codes (Z, N, V flags). So `add` performs addition without setting the condition codes, while `addcc` performas addition and sets the condition codes.